# Electron.js: main process throws "Error: Cannot find module in app.asar" in production build

Tags: node.js, electron

### Problem

I have a worker_threads worker that I'm invoking as shown below.

It works in dev but throws the following error in production build:

```
Error invoking remote method 'get-dir-items': 
Error: Cannot find module 
'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\test-app\resources\app.asar\resources\workers\fsCoreWorker.js'
```

### Code

#### `main`

```js
electron.ipcMain.handle('get-dir-items', async (event, params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const worker = new Worker('./src/workers/fsCoreWorker.js', {workerData: params})
    worker.on('message', (params) => resolve(params))
    worker.on('error', (error) => reject(error))
  })
})
```

#### `renderer`

```js
electron.ipcRenderer.invoke('get-dir-items', params)
  .then((data) => resolve(data))
  .catch((error) => reject(error))
```

It seems this declaration cannot resolve the path inside the app.asar

```
new Worker('./src/workers/fsCoreWorker.js', {workerData: params})
```

I tried extracting worker file to the resource directory, but it didn't help since it depends on other files and NPM modules that I cannot extract

#### `electron-builder config`

```
extraResources: ['src/workers/fsCoreWorker.js']
```

#### `path in main`

```js
const worker = new Worker(
  path.join(process.resourcesPath, '/src/workers/fsCoreWorker.js'), 
  {workerData: params}
)
```

Comment: You might want to try to use `extraFiles` instead of `extraResources` in your Electron Builder config and check if that solves the issue. As per [Electron Builder's documentation](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#extraresources), `extraResources` rewrites the paths passed to it.